# Including an external library functioning using namespace with xautoload

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to include the [PHPInsight](https://github.com/JWHennessey/phpInsight) library for performing sentiment analysis on user data.

Based on the demo file provided in it, I added it into the `sites/all/libraries` path so that it would read `sites/all/libraries/phpInsight` and tried to create an object

`$sentiment = new \PHPInsight\Sentiment();`

which resulted in blank screen.

Following this I looked into

1. [Include a third party library using namespaces, dependencies](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49692/include-a-third-party-library-using-namespaces-dependencies) and
2. https://www.drupal.org/node/1976234.

Apparently owing to a known constraint of D7 with namespace installed the [xautoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/xautoload) and modified the `hook_libraries_info` as below

```
function analyzer_libraries_info() {
 $libraries['phpInsight'] = array(
  'name' => 'PHP Insight',
  'vendor url' => 'https://github.com/JWHennessey/phpInsight',
  'download url' => 'https://github.com/JWHennessey/phpInsight/archive/master.zip',
  'files' => array(
    'php' => array('autoload.php'),
    ),
  'xautoload' => function($adapter) {
    $adapter->namespaceRoot('\PHPInsight', 'lib');
  },
  );
 return $libraries;
}
```

I'm still uncertain about how to use the xautoload and my autoload file that needs to be included is in `sites/all/libraries/phpInsight/autoload.php`. Since I haven't used libraries API or PHP namespaces and some clarity on what needs to be done to get it included and instantiate the object with how it happens would be of great help.

Comment: Surely `$adapter->namespaceRoot('\PHPInsight', 'lib');` would be `$adapter->namespaceRoot('\PHPInsight', 'sites/all/libraries/phpInsight');` or similar? `'lib'` would probably only make sense if the library code was at analyzer/lib/PHPInsight. You might want to change the library folder to be case sensitive too to match the library name (`PHPInsight`), that usually makes a difference with PSR-0 autoloaders IIRC

Comment: Actually maybe it should be `$adapter->namespaceRoot('\PHPInsight', 'PHPInsight');`, with the folder renamed to match the case

Comment: Can you specify the exact path to the file that defines the class?

Comment: No, according to the documentation link you posted, I think it should be `$adapter->namespaceRoot('PHPInsight', 'lib');` So without the backslash in the beginning.

Comment: You can also try `$adapter->add('PHPInsight', 'lib');`, which is the Composer syntax for PSR-0, I think to remember.

Comment: @Clive I think it was ->namespaceRoot() for PSR-0 style, and ->namespaceDeep() for PSR-4 style.. I made this myself, but don't remember it exactly :)
The ->add() and ->addPsr4() were added later, to make it feel more like Composer. I don't think that ->namespaceRoot() and ->add() are 100% equivalent, though. But for most well-written libraries they are the same - I think.

Comment: @donquixote Yeah I made quite a mess of reading the code there ;)

Comment: @donquixote @Clive thank you very much for the response, renamed the library to PHPInsight and updating the `hook_library_info` array key with same name & adding `$adapter->namespaceRoot('PHPInsight', 'lib');` did the job, If you could post it as the answer, maybe with a couple of lines detailing it I'd be happy to mark it as the accepted solution

Comment: Was the renaming of the library really necessary?