# Implement a custom PHP library into a custom block module?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a PHP class and it's files in the folder:

```
/var/www/include_php/**the_folder**
```

How should I include this into Drupal?

```
ln -sf /var/www/include_php/the_folder /var/www/drupalSite/sites/all/libraries/the_folder
```

and then do `drupal_add_library('the_folder')` or something else in my block module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your PHP Library is a class or set of classes, you can add them to the registry.  This is what I am doing in the Mobile Detect module.  I got the idea from another module, but I don't recall which one:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_registry_files_alter().
 * 
 * Adds the Mobile_Detect() class to the registry so that autoloading works.
 * See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42266 for a discussion.
 */
function mobile_detect_registry_files_alter(&$files, $modules) {
  $library_path = _mobile_detect_get_library_path();

  $files[$library_path . '/Mobile_Detect.php'] = array(
    'module' => 'mobile_detect',
    'weight' => 0,
  );
}
```

This adds the class to registry so it will be autoloaded if instantiated as `$detect = new Mobile_Detect();`.  You can edit the `$library_path = ...` line to suit your situation.

Answer (score 2):

`drupal_add_library()` is for Javascript/CSS libraries; Drupal doesn't have a similar registry for PHP libraries/classes.

To include a file inside a module in your installation, use [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) e.g.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule', 'mymodule.pages');
```

For all others just defer to the standard PHP functions (`include`/`require`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In your module symlink library's folder

```
ln -sf /var/www/include_php/the_folder /var/www/drupalSite/sites/all/mymodule/the_folder
```

Then in you mymodule.info add series of lines:

```
files[] = the_folder/first.inc
files[] = the_folder/second.inc
```

and so on. That way your module will know about them and Drupal will be able to autoload them.